# Why does a second alert not show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little program that checks if a email address contains the right elements, but it doesn't show the box that gives conformation.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sendButton").click(function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        
        if (email.indexOf('@') === -1)
        {
            alert("Please enter a valid email.");
            return;
        }
        if ((email.indexOf(".com") === -1))
        {
            alert("Please enter a valid email.");
            return;
        }
        alert(`Thank you ${name}, There has been sent a conformation to  ${email}.`);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><label for="name">Name:</label><input id="name"></p>
<p><label for="email">Email:</label><input id="email"></p>
<p><button type="button" id="sendButton">Send</button></p>
```

Is there someone who knows how to show the "Thank you" alert box?

Comment: Shouldn't you actually confirm at server that email was sent before telling user it has been? Right now all you are confirming is a button was clicked

Comment: This is just a form for a school excersice, it doesnt need to be working.

Comment: Not related to your alert, but you should look up email validation in js. Your method is not very well thought out. Related to your problem, the second alert will not show because you did a return which exits the function

Comment: It doesn't seem possible unless the button wasn't clicked again.

Comment: What browser do you run it on?

Comment: Also: consider not using `alert()` to convey user information; there's a reason that contemporary web apps don't use alerts.

Comment: I've added some sample HTML to your code snippet and it appears to work fine (as long as the email input contains "@" and ".com"). If this differs to your actual HTML code, please update the snippet

Comment: Have you looked in your browser's console for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by removing the return statement in the if statement, and put this return statement at the end of the function.

Answer (score 2):

The posted code works just fine and looks good to me. I think you might be using an old browser (i.e. probably Internet Explorer) which doesn't support template strings (these `${variableName}` symbols inside your message) and multiline strings. You can change the last `alert` to something like this:

```
alert("Thank you " + name + ", There has been sent a conformation to  " + email + ".");
```

It's basically equal to your existing code, but is compliant with the older version of the standard.